# "sameAs" structured data - should I link to reviews/Trustpilot/Tripadvisor pages?

Tags: schema.org

We've been using Google Structured data and using the `sameAs` property (on `Organization`) to refer to social network profiles.

Should this also be used to link to review pages on Trust Pilot/Trip Advisor/Reviews Websites etc.?

Comment: Interesting question. My guess is that you can as they have profile pages dedicated to your organization. They may even have your Organization markup on their pages. Also, If you display individual reviews I believe you should use the url property to link to the source of the review on those platforms. (Mainly commenting so I get a notification when someone gives a better answer).

Comment: Exactly - but cant see anything written anywhere that suggests linking to these profiles - only to link to social networks... just wondering if its a good idea or not =)

Comment: Google may pick up some social profiles from sameAs and use them in your knowedge card. It does not mean they are the only valid thing to use. As @nikant25 mentioned, they need to represent the same entity, and in my opinion a businesses page on Trust Pilot represents the same entity, just as much as a Twitter profile page.

Answer (score 1):

Since the "sameAs" field is meant to connect your brand and website with your other properties on the web, in the eyes of the search engines, I would include your additional properties in the markup. It won't hurt if you do it selectively.

That is, I would forego listing every single property, and focus on the big ones that are trusted sources. TripAdvisor's page for your business is a good candidate; some unknown review site, or a site whose only purpose is aggregating reviews, is not.

It would probably help if, somewhere on your site, you had links to the pages you're listing in your structured data's JSON-LD. For example, your social media is likely linked to from your header and/or footer and/or nav and/or Contact page. This helps search engines verify that you're linking to your own properties, you've gone public with it. If you have things like TripAdvisor or Wikipedia that you'd like in your markup, consider putting links to those on your Contact page, at the very least.

Answer (score 1):

Any trusted page on the internet that represents your organization should be linked as `sameAs` from your own website. The more `sameAs` entries, the more richly your own organization is semantically connected to the rest of the web and the more information bots can glean from your website. This cannot not have any SEO downsides as long as you trust the platforms you are linking to.

Like Henry mentioned in the other answer, it is helpful in terms of SEO to also create visible links to the pages in your `sameAs`. That shows search engines which of your properties you believe are important enough to display publicly.